# My Program is getting No responce at client.DetectDocumentText(image) GoogleVisionAPI

Tags: c#, asp.net, google-cloud-platform, ocr, google-cloud-vision

I am Trying to read a simple image but the Program is getting no response it just show the black console window. I waited for 10 mins and have followed all the steps.

I have debug the code it is getting the key file. but getting stuck at the response part.

```
using System;
using Google.Cloud.Vision.V1;

namespace GoogleOCRConsole
{
    internal class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var image = Image.FromFile("D:/Chirag/Projects/GoogleOCRConsole/GoogleOCRConsole/GoogleOCRConsole/handwriting.png");
            var client = ImageAnnotatorClient.Create();
            var response = client.DetectDocumentText(image);
            foreach (var page in response.Pages)
            {
                foreach (var block in page.Blocks)
                {
                    foreach (var paragraph in block.Paragraphs)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(string.Join("\n", paragraph.Words));
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I am totally new to this Google API. I am using the google image for this https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/images/detect_handwriting_OCR-detect-handwriting_SMALL.png

EDIT 1: Got this error after waiting for like 20 Mins 
Grpc.Core.RpcException StatusCode Unavailable Channel is in state TRANSIENT_FAILURE

How to solve this ?

Comment: There is no problem in your code! In order to verify the connection issue, use `Image.FromUri("https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/images/detect_handwriting_OCR-detect-handwriting_SMALL.png");`, instead of `Image.FromFile`; and check whether you will get the same error message or not.

Comment: Tried this, Got the same Error again.

Comment: Exactly in which line you get that exception? btw, where did you execute that code: local or cloud? and what is your OS version?

Comment: var response = client.DetectDocumentText(image); at this line i am getting the exception. I am running the code on development server of my firm. It is running windows server 2012 R2.

Comment: The same code works fine in my machine, so I think it could be an environmental issue. Please check with `Google Technical Support Team` for more help!

Comment: My guess is that you may have a proxy that doesn't support HTTP/2.0 properly. Are you able to try this in a different network environment?

Comment: @JonSkeet I havent tried it on another network. I will try it and get back to you.